# Spring Binding Request Parameters to Java Record

Tags: java, spring, record, http-request-parameters

I am trying to bind several request parameters to a Java `record`. It works if the parameters are named exactly like the `record` fields. Is there a way to bind to differently named fields, and have default values?

Example Controller

```java
@GetMapping("/invoices")
public InvoicesResponseDto queryInvoiceByDate(InvoicesByDateRequestDto requestDto) {
   ...
}
```

And what I was attempting to do in the Java `record`:

```
public record InvoicesByDateRequestDto(
        @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) LocalDate from,
        @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) LocalDate to,
        @RequestParam(value = "restricted", defaultValue = "true") Boolean isRestricted)
{}
```

When I do this the `to` and `from` fields bind correctly. However, the `isRestricted` is not bound when the parameter is passed as "restricted", but is bound when it is "isRestricted". Also, the defaultValue is not working.

I am assuming `@RequestParam` is not valid for this use case. Is there an alternative to map to different names, and support default values?

Comment: `@RequestParam` only works for controller methods so no there is no other way. There is no other way then to name the names accordingly.

Comment: You can use Jackson's `@JsonAlias` to map fields with different names. As for default values, you could probably write some code inside the record to handle it, but that kind of defeats the purpose of using a record ...